# Suse Public Cloud On-Demand Virtual Machines (VM’s) cannot receive updates

Tags: google-cloud-platform

i've suse 15 sap running on GCP and the instances (VM’s) cannot receive updates from Public Cloud On-Demand update server.

Thanks
Rajesh

Answer (score 1):

According to this [document](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000019476) provided by SUSE, there are 3 conditions in which your VMs may not receive updates:

1- An on-demand vm is launched in a network that does not have Internet access.

2- An on-demand vm routes traffic through a network device or proxy server that is hosted on-premise or in a different datacenter

3- An on-demand vm routes traffic through a network device or proxy server that is on a different public cloud platform than itself. Example: A GCP on-demand vm routes traffic through a proxy server hosted on Azure.

Comment: Thanks  yurivincki! I have that doc and the connection is allowed.